# Box2DBody not rendering LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to render a body, but it is not working. Other bodies render but this one won't. Here is the code in the Core class.

```
@Override
public void create () {

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    b2dCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    b2dCam.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / PPM, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / PPM);
    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);

    rend = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    batch = new SpriteBatch();


    entity = new CircleEntity(world, 100, 200, 10, BodyType.DynamicBody);
    entity.initBodyVariables(.1f, .1f, .1f);
    //entity.attachSprite("badlogic.jpg");
    BodyFactory.createBox(world, -1, 1f, 10000, .01f, BodyType.StaticBody, 1, 0, 0, "");

    RopeJoint j = new RopeJoint(200,300, world);
    j.create(4, 30);
}

    @Override
public void render () {
    b2dCam.update();
    cam.update();
    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
    entity.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(b2dCam.combined);


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    rend.render(world, b2dCam.combined);

    batch.begin();
    entity.render(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Here is the code for the bodyFactory:

```
public static Body createBox(World world, float x, float y, float width,
        float height, BodyType type, float density, float friction, float restitution, Object data){
    bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = type;
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(x, y));


    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(width / Core.PPM, height / Core.PPM);

    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.density = density;
    fixtureDef.friction = friction;
    fixtureDef.restitution = restitution;
    fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    fixture.setUserData(data);
    shape.dispose();


    return body;
}
```

When creating the box using this code, it renders it. I tried creating another body like this (in the CircleEntity class):

```
public class CircleEntity extends EntityParent {

/**
 * 
 * @param world
 *            of game
 * @param x
 *            position
 * @param y
 *            position
 * @param type
 *            of body (static, kinematic, dynamic)
 */
public CircleEntity(World world, float x, float y, float radius, BodyType type) {
    super(world, x, y, radius, type);
    createBody();
}

public void createBody() {
    bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.type = type;
    bodyDef.position.set(position);

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    CircleShape entityShape = new CircleShape();
    entityShape.setRadius(radius / Core.PPM);

    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = entityShape;
    fixtureDef.density = density;
    fixtureDef.friction = friction;
    fixtureDef.restitution = restitution;
    fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    entityShape.dispose();

}

@Override
public void attachSprite(String filePath) {
    super.attachSprite(filePath);
    if (entitySprite != null) {
        fixture.setUserData(entitySprite);
        body.setUserData(entitySprite);
        entitySprite.setPosition(position.x - dimensions.x, position.y - dimensions.y);
        entitySprite.setSize(dimensions.x, dimensions.y);
    }

}

@Override
public void update() {
    super.update();
    if (entitySprite != null)
        entitySprite.setPosition(position.x - dimensions.x, position.y - dimensions.y);

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D))
        body.applyForce(10, 0, position.x, position.y, true);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A))
        body.applyForce(-10, 0, position.x, position.y, true);
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
    if (entitySprite != null)
        entitySprite.draw(batch);
}

}
```

When I call this(I called it in the first set of code) it doesn't work. I can't figure out why only this entity won't render the circle. The collision still works with the body, so it is in the world but the circle itself I can't see. Any help with this is extremely appreciated.

To be clear, the Box2DBody isn't rendering, the Sprite is irrelevant.

Comment: Which part is not rendering? Does the circle show up using the box2d debug renderer or not at all? If the debug rendered shows the circle, are you saying the sprite is not displayed? You have the sprite assignment commented out. I got a bit confused as to what was not rendering.

Comment: The box2d debug renderer portion isn't rendering. But everything else renders like the ground box I made.